# Include tab code in jsx file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

I have a `jsx` file where I need to include my tab code.

If I include my tab in my `jsx`. I get this syntax error:

```
./src/views/summary/summary-view.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/workspace/src/views/summary/sports.jsx: Unexpected token (91:55)

  89 |                                     <div id="main" className="section flex-container flex-full">
  90 |                                         var Tabs = React.createClass({
> 91 |                                             displayName: 'Tabs',
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create React components inside `jsx` tags as you are attempting to do.

Rather than:

```
const Summary = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        var Tabs = React.createClass({
          ...
        });
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

You should have something like:

```
var Tabs = React.createClass({
  ...
});

const Summary = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```